# random combination of vectors

Tags: r

how can I randomly combine two vectors in R? For instance,

```
individuals <- rep(1:24)
treatments <- c("T1", "T2", "T3")
```

How can I randomly assign a treatment to an individual (from individual 1 to 24) considering that I want 3 individuals per treatment, so I end up with, let's say, a matrix with combinations between individuals and treatments.

Comment: There are multiple approaches, but you could do: `cbind.data.frame(individuals, grp=sample(rep(treatments, 8)))`. When no other args are given, the `sample` function randomly permutes the given vector.

Comment: Note that this will give you exactly *8* individuals per treatment (which is what I think you meant?), and not 3 as requested in your question.

Comment: @jbaums, thank you for your note! yes, I meant 8 and not 3 individuals per treatment. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an elegant solution but will do the job. I'm assuming you wanted a minimum of 3 individuals per treatment as a completely balanced design would give you 8 individuals per treatment.

```
individuals <- rep(1:24)
treatments <- c("T1", "T2", "T3") 

while (length(treatments[treatments=="T1"])<=3 | length(treatments[treatments=="T2"])<=3 | length(treatments[treatments=="T3"])<=3) {
    treatments = sample(treatments, length(individuals), replace = TRUE)
    print("retry")
    flush.console()
}

df <- cbind(individuals, treatments)
```